# Extract words from a List in C Shell

Tags: shell, unix

I am working on a really old version of UNIX. I have a list such as

```
x="abc xyz"
```

stored in a variable x. Now i want to store the individual strings in separate variables. Like

```
x1="abc" and x2="xyz".
```

How do I split the original string into words ? I am using sh, so I can not create arrays here.

I tried this approach

```
  col_list=`cat $outf`

    col=""
    tab=""

    for coltab in $col_list
    do
            j=0

    echo $coltab

        for ct in `echo $coltab`
            do

    echo $ct
                    case $j in
                    0)
                            col=$ct
                    ;;

                    1)
                            tab=$ct
                    ;;
                    esac

                    j=`echo "$j + 1" | bc`

         done

    echo "Column is $col"
    echo "Table is $tab"

  done
```

But this does not work. Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I haven't any idea how it will work in your ancient `sh` but *can*:

```
x="abc xyz"
read x1 x2 <<EOF
$x
EOF
echo $x1
echo $x2
```

prints

```
abc
xyz
```

BTW, your script **isn't** C-shell syntax. but vanila `sh`.

In csh, should arrays works

```
set x = "a b c"
set arr = ($x)
echo $arr[1]
```

Comment: thanks for your response. i'm afraid this does not work

Comment: for coltab in $col_list
do
read col tab <<EOF
$coltab
EOF
echo "Column is $col"
echo "Table is $tab"
done

Comment: it still saves the entire line in the variable $col

Comment: @user2334092 i havent idea what you trying to do... i gave your a solution for the question: _how to split a long string into parts and assing the parts into different variables._

Comment: so, basically i need to read a file line by line. each line has two values which i need to store in two separate variables. Now, if I proceed as you have described i see the same behavior that i was seeing earlier. Even if i do a read x1 x2 <<EOF
$x
EOF

Comment: the variable $x1 gets the entire value of $x and $x2 gets nothing !

Comment: then, your read doesn't supports multiple variables, what is strange, because the 1st shell what I used in 1987 supports. And because i haven't your shell unfortunately cant help.